# Minkowski diagram

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, observers

I have not well understood the picture of geogebra regarding the angle of time (t') that is inclined compared to (t) of 26.57°angle .
In the picture we see that the velocity is setted at 0.5c, for which i belivied that if with c = 1 is represented by a 45° inclined line, and now we want draw a speed of 0.5c, all we have to do is divide 45° by 2 and we obtain an inclinatio of 22.5°...
Somewere i have read that to have the correct inclinatio we have to do this calculation : new angle = arctan(0.5/1) = 26.57°
This is the correct solution but i have not understood why...[image]

Answer (score 1):

Coordinates of the original frame as functions of coordinates of moving frame are given by inverse lorentz transform:
$$
ct=\gamma\left(ct'+\beta x'\right)
$$
$$
x=\gamma\left(x'+\beta ct'\right)
$$
Now imagine point on the $ct´$ axis, lets say $(ct´,x´)=(1,0)$. This point will have coordinates in the original frame $(ct,x)=(\gamma,\gamma\beta)$
from which the slope is given by:
$$
\tan\alpha=\frac{\gamma\beta}{\gamma}=\beta
$$